# make a special word of a label bold

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm new to tkinter. I want to create a label that contains a text like:

This is a test.

I use this code:

```
lb = Label(window, text="This is a test.", font=("Verdana", 10))
lb.pack()
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to bold a special word in this sentence. For example is it possible to make "test" bold in this sentence?

Answer (score 0):

try this: `font='Helvetica 18 bold'`

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

var = StringVar()
label = Label( root, textvariable = var, relief = RAISED , font='Helvetica 18 bold')

var.set("Hey!? How are you doing?")
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Edit:
No, you cannot change the attributes of only some of the characters in a Label widget. If you need to style individual character you need to use a small Text widget.

For example:

```
text = tk.Text(root, height=1, font="Helvetica 12")
text.tag_configure("bold", font="Helvetica 12 bold")

text.insert("end", "Hello, ") 
text.insert("end", "world", "bold") 
text.configure(state="disabled")
```

Comment: I didn't understand how it changed a single word! suppose in your sentence, I just only `How` to be bold. How is it possible?